# Powershell script to output Size on disk

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm very new to powershell and is it possible to obtain the actual size of disk of a file? I was able to use the du, but is there another way of doing this without using that application?

Comment: _actual size of disk of a file_ does not make sense to me. Are you looking for file size or disk size. One is Get-Item and the other could be a WMI query. Either of which are easily searched even here. Perhaps you mean size __on__ disk?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554010/how-to-get-the-actual-size-on-disk-of-a-file-from-powershell

Comment: Yes I mean the "size on disk" which could be seen when you right click a folder or file, Get-Item doesnt seem to show it

Answer (score -1):

This will give you the actual size of a file in bytes:

```
(gci <insert file path> | Measure-Object -Property length -Sum).sum
```

You can then use other logic to convert to KB, MB, GB, whatever you want. You can use the same command for size of directories, with the `-Recurse` option to get the size of all subdirectories and files in the root.

Comment: This does not get you the size on disk.  This gets you the actual file size, not the size on disk.